# Trace an Entity to get all modified column name and value

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I am using Envers to audit data in my project.

Now I need to show all modified columns and their values to user.

But I am not able to get any query which can traverse an Entity to get all modified columns of that particular entity.

I found that [link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch15.html#envers-envers-tracking-properties-changes-queries), but this is not solution of my problem, I can not give all column name with "**hasChanged()**" as their is much columns in each Entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have already planned to introduce a much more efficient approach for users as a part of the next major Hibernate release.  You can find details about it here, [HHH-8058](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8058).

Comment: OKK Thank you, and  looking forward for version 6 :)